# Scale ImageView to fit without stretching

Tags: android, android-imageview

How can i fit the ImageView without stretching? [I've already tried all 'scaleType' but no one works. this image is from instagram API.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sexPE.png)

[When i use 'Matrix' scaleType.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCwBR.png)

Comment: visual guide for ScaleType also can be found here: [link](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/android-imageview-scaletype-a-visual-guide)

Answer (score 0):

Depends which side you want to fit.
You can resize bitmap if you need some custom fit.
You can use 'scaleType' `centerCrop` to fill all ImageView.

P.S. but if you want to make rectangle picture from square one, without losing some part of picture - you have no chance, it is impossible anyway.

Maybe it is better for you to resize ImageView to fit image ratio.